# Formatting UITextField not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Im trying to format my textfield for float values. Example: `0.00"` for some reason the code below works fine for other texfields, but not this one. Whats the deal? for my variables, i'm codeing them like this:

```
double var1 = [[myOtherTextField text] doubleValue];
double var2 ext...(same formatting as above, different textfield of course);
double var3 ext...(same formatting as above);

[myTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f''", (var1 + var2 - var3)]];
```

The other two textfields are formatted the same way and are showing fine...why isn't this one? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
double var1 = [[myOtherTextField text] doubleValue];
double var2 ext...(same formatting as above, different textfield of course);
double var3 ext...(same formatting as above);

[myTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f\"", (var1 + var2 - var3)]];
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! Why did I have to format this one differently?

Comment: I don't really know what you are doing with the other textfield's, but the numbers in there are setting the width and precision, and the backslash is escaping the quote. Have a look here for more info about formatting: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/